# Program type already present: okhttp3.Call$Factory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a very simple Android project that refuses to build in Android Studio and just gives me this cryptic error message:

```
Program type already present: okhttp3.Call$Factory
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: okhttp3.Call$Factory, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/easywsdl/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation files('libs/easywsdl/ExKsoap2-1.0.2.0.jar')
}
```

How can I troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your .jar should already contain `okHttp3`, and this is probably why there is an issue with `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'`.

If you remove this dependency, you should not get the error.

You can print a tree of all the dependencies used with `gradlew app:dependencies` (where app is the name of the module used for your application, and usually the default name when you create a new android app project)

Comment: I'm not directly using okhtpp3 library but I'm using twitter's core library which includes okhttp3 library, what will I do then? I have to use both twitter core and ksoap2 (which cause the crash)