# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro'

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying okhttp and i have the next error:\

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro'

This is what i have in my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.woooba.login2"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is the MainActivity.java

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String u = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22k";
task.execute(u);
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(u).build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
           if (response.isSuccessful()){
             Log.i("Response", response.body().string());
           }
         }
  });
```

Anyone know what happen? It said ' More that one file was found' but not sure what it is talking about. I am new with android

Thanks

UPDATE
proguard-rules.pro code displayed as per @vivek request

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

UPDATE 2
Adding to build.grade within android{} the next:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license)

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro'
}
```

Pressed "Sync now" and play and the error's gone but when you go to 4:run I see another error.

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'

So i added to packagingOptions{}

> exclude 'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'

and I get the next error

> Compilation failed to complete

Android issues:

> Program type already present: okhttp3.Call$Factory Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present: okhttp3.Call$Factory,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Any idea? i've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098769/program-type-already-present-okhttp3-callfactory) that suggest to remove the implementation of okhttp3 but come up erros when I call this class in MainActivity

> OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Comment: show your proguard file

Comment: @VivekMishra done. I havent got anything there. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342455/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-meta-inf-license

Comment: thanks @VivekMishra. tried that and other instructions but still having problems.

Comment: if that didn't try with some older versions of okhttp library

Comment: good idea. I'll give some time just in case that someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your build is attempting to include multiple copies of OkHttp in your binary. Do any of your dependencies include their own copies of OkHttp? Are you including multiple versions?

Comment: Hi @Jesse. Thanks for your reply.
It is a new android's project. Just playing around with it. You can see above all the dependencies.
Maybe the problem come from this implementation that was created by default?
> implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
I dont think so because when i remove

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'

i have an error when i call okhttp3 class